# Collision detection of a ball with an arc

Tags: math, libgdx, game-physics

I am making a simple game in which i have a ball and an arc revolving around the center. When user touches the screen the ball moves in the direction of pointer and hits the arc. But i am not able to find any method to detect that collision
 An image has been attached for better understanding

[image: Game Image]
Game image

[image: Debug File]

Debug Snapshot..

I have a circle bound around my ball...
What i am doing is

> Detecting the point of intersection of ball center and circle on which arc is >revolving.
>   But i am not able to detect whether the arc was there when ball intersected the circle??
>   please help...:'(

Code for making arc:

```
 public void arc (float x, float y, float radius, float start, float degrees,int segments) {
  //  int segments = (int)(6 * (float)Math.cbrt(radius) * (degrees / 360.0f));

    if (segments <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("segments must be > 0.");
    float colorBits = color.toFloatBits();
    float theta = (2 * MathUtils.PI * (degrees / 360.0f)) / segments;
    float cos = MathUtils.cos(theta);
    float sin = MathUtils.sin(theta);
    float cx = radius * MathUtils.cos(start * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
    float cy = radius * MathUtils.sin(start * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);

    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
        renderer.color(colorBits);
        Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(10);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        renderer.vertex(x + cx, y + cy, 0);
        float temp = cx;
        cx = cos * cx - sin * cy;
        cy = sin * temp + cos * cy;
        renderer.color(colorBits);
        renderer.vertex(x + cx, y + cy, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your arc defined? You may compare whether angle of intersection is within arc limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is an arc? Simply: the difference of two circles, constrained within two vectors (or a triangle).

A diagram may be helpful;

[image: Diagram]

The radius of the larger red circle equals the outer radius of the arc. The radius of the smaller blue circle equals the inner radius of the arc, minus the diameter of the ball. The triangle shows the edges of the arc.

From here, just test the euclidean distance of the ball [from the center] against the radii of the circles, then find the two tangents from the origin to the ball and see if either of them fall pass through the angular measure of the arc.

EDIT: Realized I need something like this in my own project, so I decided to write it up;

```
    double ball_radius = //Your radius of the ball

    //the start and end angles of the arc
    double start = //i.e -PI/4;
    double end = //i.e PI/4;

    double innerRadius = //inner radius of arc
    double outerRadius = innerRadius + [width of lines, 10 in your code]

    /* Now all the fun mathsy stuff */

    boolean collides = false;

    double dx = bx - cx; //[bx, by] = ball coords
    double dy = by - cy; //[cx, cy] = center coords

    //get distance and direction to ball from center
    double dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    double dir = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    //angles for tangents to ball from center
    double tangent_angle =  Math.asin(ball_radius/ dist);
    double dir0 = dir + tangent_angle;
    double dir1 = dir - tangent_angle;

    //check if distance is good
    if (dist + ball_radius> innerRadius && dist - ball_radius < outerRadius)
    {
        //check edges of ball against start and end of arc
        boolean d = dir > start && dir < end;
        boolean d0 = dir0 > start && dir0 < end;
        boolean d1 = dir1 > start && dir1 < end;

        //if both tangents are inside the angular measure
        if (d || d0 && d1)
        {
            collides = true;
        }
        //otherwise if one tangent is inside
        //We need to test the outside corners more precisely
        else if (d0 != d1)
        {
                double x0 = cx + outerRadius * Math.cos(start) - bx;
                double y0 = cy + outerRadius * Math.sin(start) - by;

                double x1 = cx + outerRadius * Math.cos(end) - bx;
                double y1 = cy + outerRadius * Math.sin(end) - by;

                /** And so on for the other 2 corners */
                /** If the arc is very thick, you will need to test against
                    the actual line segments at the ends of the arc */

                if (x0 * x0 + y0 * y0 < ball_radius * ball_radius
                    || x1 * x1 + y1 * y1 < ball_radius * ball_radius)
                    collides = true;

        }
    }
```

If the ball is only ever going to hit the inside of the arc, or 3-4 pixels of imprecision is okay when hitting the corners of the arc, then you can replace the entire if-condition in the above code with this, which is way more efficient (but messes up on the corners very slightly);

```
if (dist > innerRadius - ball_radius && dist + ball_radius < outerRadius)
{
    //if any tangent falls within the arc
    collides = ((dir0 > start && dir0 < end) || (dir1 > start && dir1 < end));
}
```

End result:

[image: End Result]

Comment: Loved your response....thanks a ton....it gave me another approach, i read this thing somewhere but dont know how it skipped from my mind...Thanks a lot..:)

Comment: What is `radius` in this case??

Comment: Ah, my bad, all the `radius` are the same as `ball_radius`. I modified the code as I pasted it into the answer, looks like some things got messed up. Edited and fixed.

Comment: i dont know why but
`if (d || d0 && d1) {
                    collides = true;
                } ` is true everytime

Comment: That's weird... If it still breaks with some extra brackets; `if (d || (d0 && d1))` then idk why that would be happening.

Comment: Sir, for you i have uploaded the image have a look

Comment: I see no new images... I would firstly make sure that you're using radians and degrees where appropriate (everything in my code is radians). Secondly, make sure that `start` is always less than `end`.

Comment: ok in my case its in degrees, i will test it again and let you know..:)

Comment: KookieMonster i need your help again......the approach which u provided is working fine but it is having `unpredictable behaviour` when my `arc` is `in 4th quad` and `ball is not having any collision` with the arc when the arc is in or the `start` angle is in `1st quad`

i have modified my images for you..

Comment: Yeah, you do need a little bit of extra logic to test if the angle is contained. Something like this: http://www.xarg.org/2010/06/is-an-angle-between-two-other-angles/

Comment: ok i got it...thanks for the help again...:)
you are really a saviour...:)

Comment: ok this is NOT related to this question i wanted to reach  @Kookie and i dont know why i think you can help me with this too...[I am in trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007151/game-running-slow-in-android-handsets-no-use-of-textures-only-using-shaperender) please have a look at this.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

> arc (float x, float y, float radius, float start, float degrees

It seems that `x,y` is circle center, `start` is starting angle, `degrees` is sweep angle, so end angle is `end = start + degrees`

If your intersection point is `ix, iy`, then you can check signs of these cross products:

```
cp_1 = (ix-x)*sin(start)-(iy-y)*Cos(start) 
cp_2 = (ix-x)*sin(end)-(iy-y)*Cos(end)
```

If cp1 has negative sign and cp2 is positive (for positive arc direction Degrees), then `(ix,iy)` intersection point is between `(start,end)` arc ends. (works for `Abs(degrees) < Pi=180`)

Delphi example generate arc from -15 to +30 degrees, and check whether rays from `cx,cy` to some points intersect this arc:

```
  function IsPointInArcLimits(cx, cy, ix, iy, StartAngle, Deg: Double): Boolean;
  var
    EndAngle, cp_1, cp_2: Double;
  begin
    EndAngle := DegToRad(StartAngle + Deg);
    StartAngle := degToRad(StartAngle);
    cp_1 := (ix - cx) * Sin(StartAngle) - (iy - cy) * Cos(StartAngle);
    cp_2 := (ix - cx) * Sin(EndAngle) - (iy - cy) * Cos(EndAngle);
    Result := (cp_1 <= 0) and (cp_2 >= 0);
  end;

var
  cx, cy, ix, iy, StartAngle, Degrees: Integer;
begin
  cx := 0;
  cy := 0;
  ix := 10;
  StartAngle := -15;
  Degrees := 45;
  for iy := -5 to 7 do
    if IsPointInArcLimits(cx, cy, ix, iy, StartAngle, Degrees) then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Yes  y=%d an=%f    arc %d+%d',
        [iy, RadToDeg(ArcTan(iy / ix)), StartAngle, Degrees]))
    else
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('No y=%d an=%f    arc %d+%d',
        [iy, RadToDeg(ArcTan(iy / ix)), StartAngle, Degrees]));
```

output:

```
No y=-5 an=-26.57    arc -15+45
No y=-4 an=-21.80    arc -15+45
No y=-3 an=-16.70    arc -15+45
Yes  y=-2 an=-11.31    arc -15+45
Yes  y=-1 an=-5.71    arc -15+45
Yes  y=0 an=0.00    arc -15+45
Yes  y=1 an=5.71    arc -15+45
Yes  y=2 an=11.31    arc -15+45
Yes  y=3 an=16.70    arc -15+45
Yes  y=4 an=21.80    arc -15+45
Yes  y=5 an=26.57    arc -15+45
No y=6 an=30.96    arc -15+45
No y=7 an=34.99    arc -15+45
```

Comment: i will try it for sure and will definitely upvote your answer if it solves my problem..Thanks

Comment: Abs(degrees) < Pi=180
what does this means

Comment: Arc less then PI, the same - arc less than 180 degrees

Comment: you did gave me an approach...i tried it....but its not helping...i am trying something else lets hope it behaves as i want it to.. will post it soon..:)

Comment: I am new to these things...thanks a ton...:)
what i did is:
`double ngle = Math.atan2(pointerbound.y - pointerorigin.y,pointerbound.x - pointerorigin.x);` to find angle of projection of pointer...
after that i had the start and end angle....i found the intersection of arc and my pointer there i compared wheter the pointer angle is within arc angles...

Comment: Is `pointerorigin` also center of arc? If you found `ngle`, you may just compare it with arc limits (but take care about zero transition etc)

Comment: Yes sir its center of arc....yes i have taken care of this thing..thanks for suggestions..:)

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to find the segments which make up the arc, then you could use the `Intersector` class to check if the circle collides with each segment. I don't know how you're making your arc so I don't know if you can get the segments or not.