# Ball Motion Effect libgdx

Tags: libgdx

How can i add a motion effect on a ball as shown in image.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the ball is the only moving element the easiest way to achieve this is to clear screen with a semi-transparent color:

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.5f);
```

If not you can implement a queue that will keep your ball's last positions and will render a ball there with descending transparency. In pseudo code it could be something like

```
    //render() method
    for(int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
        transparency = i * 1/queue.size();
        draw(ball, queue.get(i), transparency);

    draw(ball, currentBallPosition)

    queue.put(currentBallPosition)
    if(queue.size() > 20) //we want to keep last 20 positions
        queue.removeLast()
```

Another nice idea is to use [Particle Effects](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Particle-Editor) although it will not always do the thing (like when your ball can change color or shape)

Comment: this approach seems to be good..i will try and let you know whether it did my work or not,....:)

Comment: Please provide more explain about your code. What is draw method?
, What is the Items which `Queue` contains?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663160/collision-detection-of-a-ball-with-an-arc/36717254#36717254) is a link to ui of my game , i want to show the motion effect when the ball shoots the arc.