# Game Running slow in Android Handsets, no use of textures only using ShapeRenderer to draw shapes

Tags: libgdx, game-physics

I am making a game in which i am making **arcs** using **ShapeRenderer**, As i needed to **rotate those arcs around the center** so i wrote that code only `begin` and `end` in **render** method, I am **initializing them in create method**,
But as the **number of arcs increases** the **game gets slower** and slower. I have **maximum of 13 arcs and minimum 2 arcs**.
It running fine till few say 8 arcs and after that it gets slower.
Please any one out there if he/she can help, please help...
thanks in advance.

**Render Method is having 5 loops, I don't have any choice to get rid of them.**

this is in create:

`for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            random = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
            a[i] = new Arc(arcColors[random]);
            arcs_visible[i] = 1;
            pointercolor[i] = a[i].getArcColor();
            a[i].begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        }`

this is in render:

```
private void draw_one_arc(int i, double radius, float startangle, float sweep) {
        if (arcs_visible[i] == 1 && collides[i] == false) {

            a[i].arc(pointerorigin.x + pointer.getWidth() / 2, pointerorigin.y + pointer.getWidth() / 2, (float) radius, startangle, sweep, 100);
        }

    }
```

`

Comment: Can you share any of your code?

Comment: Probably need more information. You can't fix a problem if the exact cause is not known. You should use a profiler to see exactly which methods are slowing things down. The only thing off the top of my head, is to make sure everything is being batched with the same `ShapeRenderer` instance.

Comment: ok i fixed the issue...i was creating arc again and again....cauz i was in need of rotating it....i was doing that in a loop which was for rotation, i simply created my arc before that loop and its done...:)